# How can I optimize the design?

Tags: mongodb

**Use case:**

I am selling devices. Each device sends me the data back. I am calculating the issues with each device.

**Device Info:**

- customer name
- location sold
- device id
- device group

**Issue information:**

- Issue ID
- Issue detail
- Issue severity
- Issue status
- Issue can be shown to customer

**My current design:**

```
  {
  _id : device Id | issue id,
  device id : "123",
  ... //all device fields
  issue_id:"12",
  //all issue fields
  }
```

It is not a nested doc. It is flatten structure.

**Problem with this structure:**

Issue information should be unique across all the devices. But issue fields like issue severity and issue detail are different per system. Unique issues are 20K. I have 10 million documents which means total issues I have 10million across all of my devices. Because of this flatten structure, I had to update all the issues for every message from each device. It is inefficient. I am thinking of having something like below.

**Thought process:**

Single document structure is as follows.

```
 {
  issue_id: "12",
  issue_desc: "add",
  issue_public: "No",
  devices:{
   deviceId_one: {
    device_id:
    //all device details
    //issue_recieved_time
    //issue_severity
   },
   deviceId_two: {
   }
  }
```

My problem with this new design is that how do I query all the issues associated with device Id 2. Since the device id field is dynamic.

I read that mongodb is not meant for joining. Because I am expecting the following similar queries to be responded in milliseconds.

1. Find all the issue information which are requested for a device group
2. Find all the issue information which are sold to single customer
3. Find all the counts like that can be shown / not shown to the customer along with severity such as critical, severe, high, low etc.

   public high count
   public severe count
   private high count

I am fine with new datasource. But looking w.r.t mongodb especially now. Any ideas please?

Comment: You may define `devices` as array (`device`:[{device1}, {device2}]), it's indexable, easy to update, etc...

Comment: What's issue and device cardinality? 1:N, N:1 or N:M?

Comment: @Valijon One device can have one or more issues. Issue is something update failed / update required / motherboard failed / storage is full kind of things. One issue can be part of 10million devices. I have around 20 device fields. Is it scalable if I keep device as an array

Comment: I think this [design](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7EWr7TjtJpJ) fits better for your usecase. It's easy to update, query, etc...

Comment: @Valijon There are chances that document size can cross more than 16MB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use time based bucketing. Make use of `issue_recieved_time` field to create buckets. Bucket granularity depends on frequency of issues.

For example - hourly

```
{
  "issue_id":"12",
  "issue_desc":"add",
  "issue_public":"No",
  "start_date":"2019-03-25T10:00:00.000Z",
  "end_date":"2019-03-25T10:59:59.000Z",
  "devices":[
    {
      "device_group":1,
      "issue_recieved_time":"2019-03-25T10:00:00.000",
      "issue_severity":"high",
      "show":true
    },
    .....
    {
      "device_id":10,
      "issue_recieved_time":"2019-03-25T10:30:00.000Z",
      "issue_severity":"low"
      "show":false
    }
  ]
}
```

> Find all the issue information which are requested for a device group

```
db.collectionname.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"devices.device_group":1}},
  {"$addFields":{
    "issues_devices":{
      "$map":{
        "input":{
          "$filter":{
            "input":"$devices",
            "cond":{"$eq":["$$this.device_group",1]}
          }
        },
        "in":{
          "issue_recieved_time":"$$this.issue_recieved_time",
          "issue_severity":"$$this.issue_severity"
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$issues_devices"},
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":{"$mergeObjects":["$$ROOT","$issues_devices"]}}},
  {"$project":{"issues_devices":0}}
])
```

> Find all the issue information which are sold to single customer

Similar to above with customer filter

> Find all the counts like that can be shown / not shown to the customer
>   along with severity such as critical, severe, high, low etc.

```
db.collectionname.aggregate([
  {"$unwind":"$devices"},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{"show":"$devices.show","severity":"$devices.issue_severity"}, 
    "count":1
  }}
])
```

> But I should get the latest issue information

```
db.collectionname.aggregate([
  {"$sort":{"end_date":-1}},
  {"$group":{
     "_id":"$issue_id",
     "latest":{"$first":"$$ROOT"}
  }},
  //additional stages if you need to pull in the issue information from devices
  {"$addFields":{
    "issues_devices":{
      "$map":{
        "input":"$latest",
        "in":{
          "issue_recieved_time":"$$this.issue_recieved_time",
          "issue_severity":"$$this.issue_severity"
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$issues_devices"},
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":{"$mergeObjects":["$$ROOT","$issues_devices"]}}},
  {"$project":{"issues_devices":0}}
])
```

Comment: Thanks. But I should get the latest issue information. With this design, is it possible?

Comment: I will really give a try on this. My doubt is that what would be the performance of these queries.

Comment: That is hard to say. I don’t have the data that you have. You have to try it out. I can suggest optimizations based on your findings.

Comment: Let's say today one device sends the update for issue1. issue1 is part of device2 where we received information one week ago. When I query, will I get the device2 info also?

Comment: If they belong to same device group the query 1 in the answer will pull both devices.

Comment: Do you mean same device array? What is same group here?

Comment: Not sure which query you are referring . Depends on what field you are querying. You will get both of you need. Please try queries out.